# Angularjs data-toggle = dropdown Not Working with Select Option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In My Code I used simple dropdown bind with option using ng-repeat but when I bind that, it display nothing due to some extra class enabled may be in javascript. My normal code is :

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
     <label>Select Employee</label>

     <select class="form-control show tick" id="selectEmp" name="toEmployeeCode" required="" ng-model="toEmployeeCode">
     <option value="">Select Team Member</option>
         <option ng-repeat="x in AllEmployee" value="{{x.EmployeeCode}}">{{x.FirstName}} {{x.MiddleName}} {{x.LastName}}</option>
           </select>
          </div>
```

But when it load display

```
  <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control tick">
   <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-round 
     btn-simple" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="selectEmp" 
      title="Select Team Member" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="filter-option pull-left">Select Team Member</span>&nbsp; 
           <span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span>
  </button>

   <div class="dropdown-menu" role="combobox">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false">
      <li data-original-index="0" class="selected">
         <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria- 
           disabled="false" aria-selected="true">
            <span class="text">Select Team Member</span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                   </a>
       </li>
        <li data-original-index="1">
             <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria- 
                disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
               <span class="text ng-binding">  </span>
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
             </a>
        </li>
       </ul>
  </div>
     <select class="form-control show tick ng-pristine ng-untouched ng- 
        invalid ng-invalid-required" id="selectEmp" name="toEmployeeCode" 
         required="" ng-model="toEmployeeCode" tabindex="-98" aria- 
      required="true">
           <option value="">Select Team Member</option>
        <option ng-repeat="x in AllEmployee" value="EMP-1004" class="ng- 
            binding ng-scope">ABC</option> 
           <option ng-repeat="x in AllEmployee" value="EMP-1007" class="ng- 
           binding ng-scope">PQR</option>
           <option ng-repeat="x in AllEmployee" value="EMP-1008" class="ng- 
                  binding ng-scope">ASD</option>
           <option ng-repeat="x in AllEmployee" value="EMP-1009" class="ng- 
            binding ng-scope">ZXC</option>
           <option ng-repeat="x in AllEmployee" value="EMP-1010" class="ng- 
             binding ng-scope">HUK</option>
                                        </select>
      </div>
```

But it does not work when i use my code it will not display

I use angularjs

```
      var app = angular.module('App', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ng-repeat` in `<option>`, it works incorrectly. Use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) in select instead.

[Stop ng-repeating options: use ng-options](http://www.codelord.net/2016/08/12/stop-ng-repeating-options-use-ng-options/)

Comment: <select class="form-control show-tick"  id="selectEmp" 
        name="toEmployeeCode" required="" ng-model="toEmployeeCode" 
                                                ng-option="emp.EmployeeCode as emp.FirstName 
        for emp in AllEmployee">
                                                <option value="">Select Team Member</option>
                                                
                                            </select>

Comment: `<select class="form-control show-tick ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="selectEmp" name="toEmployeeCode" required="" ng-model="toEmployeeCode" ng-option="emp.EmployeeCode as emp.FirstName for emp in AllEmployee" tabindex="-98" aria-required="true">
                                                <option value="">Select Team Member</option>
                                                
                                            </select>` but it not display link